# Load online SQLite database from google drive to a iOS app in Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I want to host my SQLite database online, but I don't know how to import it. Right now the table is being created in default document directory. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var database: Connection!
    let boxesTable = Table("boxes1")
    let ID = Expression<Int>("ID")
    let SNO = Expression<String>("Serial_Number")
    let condition = Expression<String>("Condition")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        do{
           let doucumentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            let fileUrl = doucumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("boxes1").appendingPathExtension("sqlite3")
            let database = try Connection(fileUrl.path)
            self.database = database
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }

        let createTable = self.boxesTable.create { (table) in
            table.column(self.ID, primaryKey: true)
            table.column(self.SNO, unique: true)
            table.column(self.condition)
        }

        do{
            try self.database.run(createTable)
            print("Created Table")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
}
```

And here is the link of my sqlite database :-

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7H7vc34uAM6WEVKUC1YeFQ5VkE

I gave this link an editable access using Swift 3 to code.

**One more question: do I give the link to my folder or the file directly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoudn't do that. SQLite isn't design to be used on a host like a regular database.

SQLite is a library and your real data is just a file on disk. To use it online it would be necessary to use a server and make that server use SQLite library to write on SQLite database file.

But SQLite wasn't designed to be used on a server.

> SQLite is an in-process library that implements a self-contained,
>   **serverless**, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.
>
> SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine. Unlike most other SQL
>   databases, SQLite does not have a separate server process. **SQLite
>   reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files**.

To do that, you should use another service like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=pt-br) for example.

From [SQLite official website](https://www.sqlite.org/about.html).